# Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.SingleObserver<okhttp3.ResponseBody>)'

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

```
SingleObserver < ResponseBody > singleObserver = new SingleObserver < ResponseBody > () {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {
        Log.w("ABC", "S");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) {
        try {
            Log.w("ABC", responseBody.string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
        Log.w("ABC", e.getMessage());
    }
};
RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).build().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
retrofitInterface.getMainData(1).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(singleObserver); //The Error Here
```

I'm trying to use SingleObserver with the `subscribe` method but I getting this error.

**Error**

```
Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.SingleObserver<okhttp3.ResponseBody>)'
```

Comment: What is the definition of `RetrofitInterface`. My guess is that you have RxJava 2 and 3 mixed in the same project.

Comment: @akarnokd I fixed the problem changed it from Observable<ResponseBody> to Single<ResponseBody> from interface, Thanks

Comment: If you solved your problem then please post it as an answer, not in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem: changed it from `Observable< ResponseBody >` to `Single< ResponseBody >` from interface.